# Frustrating Excel-VBA Calculation Puzzle - function always returns = #N/A

Tags: excel, calculation, vba

I've got some formulas that, when an input value on a cell on another sheet in the same workbook is changed, display either #NA or #VALUE! until I open that sheet and manually trigger calculation, even though everything is set to Automatic Calculation and the VBA custom functions are set to Application.Volitile. When I run the Evaluate Formula routine in Excel on one typical cell and Evaluate down to nearly the last step I get an evaluation that reads as follows;

```
= IF(FALSE,#N/A,1076)
```

and expect the next step when I hit Evaluate to be

=1076

but instead it returns

= #N/A

and the only thing to do is manually calculate using Calculate Now or a key combination. Then all the cells return correct answers and there are no error messages.

**What's going on??????**

[image]

Comment: What is the actual formula before evaluation?

Comment: Well, its this:                       =IF(B51="","",DtoRiser(C51,B51,G50)+insertspace(C51)),                   where DtoRiser and insertspace are both VBA custom functions. Setpping through the Evaluation, all the terms are being evaluated correctly right up until the final #NA. In the screen shot the FALSE and #NA and 1076 are all the expected returns.

Comment: Or should a FALSE evaluation of the IF statement return a value rather than a #NA? It did in the previous Evaluation window step.

Comment: The `#N/A` is inserted into the True leg of the formula as the first part of the False leg is evaluated.  (I checked that there was nothing unusual about that by replacing your functions with `SUM`s.)  I think I'm stumped - no idea at all as to what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Anyway! I will keep trying to track it down.

Comment: I assume your `DtoRiser` and `insertspace` functions both just return a numeric value, and don't try to do anything funny (like changing cell contents etc).

Comment: That's right. Just a numerical value.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of the cell(s) this is being run on would help (especially what `B51` is)?  I understand why `#N/A` is being returned from `=IF(FALSE,#N/A,1076)`...Maybe it'll help to see what `DtoRiser` is?

Comment: I'm not sure it will help, but here are three screen shots - 1 after manually choosing Calculate Now from the menu, 2 after one of the input values has changed on another sheet, and 3 with an error message revealed for the cell that appears to be the first one of the bunch that fails (each column is executing the same formula from row 2 to 270).

Comment: The error message says that a wrong data type is used in the formula, but it calculates it properly when you hit Control+= or calculation from the menu. The data types in for the four inputs to the formula in the VBA function SetRowElev are String, Integer, Double, Double and in excel the target cells are Text, Number, Number, Number.

Comment: sorry - need to figure out how to add screen shot...

Comment: Link to the three screen shots: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c0qh73ijaqynmdq/AACAFjs0Zm9wRLr6rbzbHZdha?dl=0